# How to find all possible strings after deleting k number of characters from the given string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

For example we have a string s = "stackoverflow" .if we delete **one** character then we get "tackoverflow", "sackoverflow", "stckoverflow" ... and so on.
How to get all possible strings when we delete k number of characters where k < len(s).

We can do by for loop for given exact number of characters to delete and string.But how to do it when number of characters to delete is not fixed.

Comment: i have no idea how to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`itertools` is your friend:

```
from itertools import combinations

s = "stack overflow"
n_delete = 1

print([''.join(i) for i in combinations(s, len(s) - n_delete)])
```